# Code to read each row of date in database table

Tags: php, date, row

Currently, I develop a system that will notify user when the warranty of their product will expired soon. If the date is less than 45 days, then an email will send automatically to me. For now, I use below code to send the email.  It can run without problem.

```
$days = (strtotime("2013-9-23") - strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) / (60 * 60 * 24);
if ($days<45)
    include 'sendmail.php';
else {
    echo "Problem!";
}
```

It might be impossible to code the date one by one. So, I'm thinking that the system can read each row of date in the table itself, but I have no idea to do it. What should I do, so that the code above can read the data without specific it like "2013-9-23" etc.

My full code is :

```
// set database server access variables: 
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$pass = ""; 
$db = "master_inventory";

// open connection 
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 

// select database 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 


// create query 
$query = 'SELECT Lap_PC_Name, Lap_War_Expiry FROM laptop';
$date = 'SELECT Lap_War_Expiry FROM laptop';
// execute query 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

// see if any rows were returned 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 

$days = (strtotime($date) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) / (60 * 60 * 24);
if ($days<45)
    include 'sendmail.php';
else {
    echo "Problem!";
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $Lap_PC_Name = $row['Lap_PC_Name'];
    $Lap_War_Expiry = $row['Lap_War_Expiry'];
}
```

My sendmail.php code :

```
<?php
// set database server access variables: 
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$pass = ""; 
$db = "master_inventory";

// open connection 
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 

// select database 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 

// create query 
$query = "SELECT * FROM laptop"; 

// execute query 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

// see if any rows were returned 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 10) {
    for ($query=1; $query<=$result; $query++){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $Lap_PC_Name = $row['Lap_PC_Name'];
            $Lap_War_Expiry = $row['Lap_War_Expiry'];
        }
    }
    $to       = 'nazeni@domain.com';
    $subject  = 'Testing sendmail';
    $message  = 'The Following licensed will expired in less than one month. PC           
    Name:'.$Lap_PC_Name. '.The license will expire on '.$Lap_War_Expiry;
    $headers  = 'From: nazeni@domain.com';

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "Email sent.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Email sending failed.";
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please update your question with detail and more code.

Comment: @sala Uddin I have edited my question and explain more about it. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give more details. Where do your datas come from ?
Anyway, when you have to filter your datas, you may filter them at different places : when you get the datas (when possible), or after you get the datas.

For example, if datas come from database, you have a choice : 
1/ use SQL request to get only pertinent datas then send mailfor these cases.

```
sample SQL code given by liyakat (see above)
```

2/ get all datas from database, and process each row with your code, replacing the hard coded date with the date from the database.

```
foreach($db_results as $row) {
    $days = (strtotime($row['date']) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))/ (60 * 60 * 24);
    if ($days < 45) {
        include 'sendmail.php';
    else {
        echo "Problem!";
    }
}
```

The first solution is more performant, as you don't have to get and process *all* the datas.

Comment: I've updated my question with my full coding. Can you explain more about **$db_results as $row** ? What should I declare with it ? Sorry, I'm still a beginner in php and developing system.

Comment: That was a shortcut to say that for each database row of result, you have to test the date field. You may move your date test code (your first code snippet) inside your while loop (to test each row). Your test will then be against $row['Lap_War_Expiry'].

Comment: Thanks to you and Likayat for excellent answer. I run the code already, but it will only print one data from the table. Can you give me an idea on how to display all data that is less than 45 ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with mysql it would be good approach

```
CREATE TABLE t (d1 timestamp, d2 timestamp);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 05:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 00:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-10 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-10 12:00:00', '2010-04-01 13:00:00');

SELECT d2, d1, DATEDIFF(d2, d1) AS diff FROM t;

+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| d2                  | d1                  | diff |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 2010-03-30 05:00:00 | 2010-03-11 12:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-11 12:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-11 00:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-10 12:00:00 |   20 |
| 2010-04-01 13:00:00 | 2010-03-10 12:00:00 |   22 |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

or also you can add query like

```
 SELECT d2, d1, DATEDIFF(d2, d1) AS diff FROM t where DATEDIFF(d2, d1) < 45 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// $date is get from table
$days = (strtotime($date) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))/ (60 * 60 * 24);
if ($days < 45) {
    include 'sendmail.php';
else {
    echo "Problem!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant idea. After I edited the code, the notification email sent to me only contain one data from the table. It supposed to be more than one data. I've updated my question. Can you please check where I'm lacking ? Thanks in advance !